# How can I get the data in the adapter and display it in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have trouble getting data from adapter to fragment. I want to display some information through recycler view but the problem is that I have an error in getting the data arraylist in my VaccineAdapter.

**This is my patientlogin class** once the user login the account. I want to display his/her personal information as well as the his her vaccine history in a recyclerView order.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_login);

        name = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        IdNo = findViewById(R.id.idNumber);

    }
    // Validate name
    private Boolean validateName(){
        String val = name.getText().toString();

        if(val.isEmpty()){
            name.setError("Field is Empty");
            return false;
        }else{
            name.setError(null);
            name.setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Validate ID number
    private Boolean validateIdNumber(){
        String val = IdNo.getText().toString();

        if(val.isEmpty()){
            IdNo.setError("Field cannot be empty");
            return false;
        }else{
            IdNo.setError(null);
            name.setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

        public void loginPatient(View view){

        //validate Login info
        if (!validateName() | !validateIdNumber()) {
            return;
        }else{
            isUser();
        }
    }
    //if validation is correct
    private void isUser() {

        final String userEnteredIdNo = IdNo.getText().toString().trim();
        final String userEnteredName = name.getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Patient List");

        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(userEnteredIdNo);

        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    IdNo.setError(null);
                    IdNo.setEnabled(false);

                    String IdNoFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("name").getValue(String.class);

                    if(IdNoFromDB.equals(userEnteredName)){
                        IdNo.setError(null);
                        IdNo.setEnabled(false);

                        String imageFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("image").getValue(String.class);
                        String idFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("id").getValue(String.class);
                        String nameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String ageFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("age").getValue(String.class);
                        String birthdayFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("birthday").getValue(String.class);
                        String addressFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("address").getValue(String.class);
                        String vaccineNameFromDB= dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("vaccine_Name").getValue(String.class);
                        String institutionNameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("institution_Name").getValue(String.class);
                        String vaccineDateFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredIdNo).child("vaccine_Date").getValue(String.class);

                        PatientInfoHelperClass helperClass = new PatientInfoHelperClass(imageFromDB , idFromDB , nameFromDB , ageFromDB , birthdayFromDB ,addressFromDB ,vaccineNameFromDB , vaccineDateFromDB , institutionNameFromDB);

                        Intent intent = new Intent( patientLogin.this , patientProfile.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable("helperClass", Parcels.wrap(helperClass));
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else{
                        name.setError("No such name exists");
                        name.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    IdNo.setError("Wrong Id Number");
                    IdNo.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**This is my VaccineAdapter** this is the adapter

```
 public VaccineAdapter(Context context, List<PatientInfoHelperClass> mList) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VaccineAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vaccine_list,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VaccineAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //get data
        String vName = mList.get(position).getVaccine_Name();
        String iName = mList.get(position).getInstitution_Name();
        String vDate = mList.get(position).getVaccine_Date();

        //set data
        holder.vaccine_Name.setText(vName);
        holder.institution_Name.setText(iName);
        holder.vaccine_Date.setText(vDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView vaccine_Name, institution_Name, vaccine_Date;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        vaccine_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vaccineName);
        institution_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.institutionName);
        vaccine_Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vaccineDate);
    }
}
```

**This is my HistoryFragment** connected to vaccine adapter where I want to display vaccine history in a recyclerview order.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<PatientInfoHelperClass> mList;
VaccineAdapter adapter;

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment HistoryFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static HistoryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

    HistoryFragment fragment = new HistoryFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    bundle.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.historyRecyclerView);
    mList = args.getParcelable("helperClass");
    adapter = new VaccineAdapter (getActivity(), mList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return v;
}
```

**This is my PatientInfoHelperClass**

```
   @Parcel
public class PatientInfoHelperClass {
    String image, name, id, age, birthday, address, institution_Name, vaccine_Name, vaccine_Date;

    public PatientInfoHelperClass() {
    }

    public PatientInfoHelperClass(String image, String name, String id, String age, String birthday, String address, String institution_Name, String vaccine_Name, String vaccine_Date) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.address = address;
        this.institution_Name = institution_Name;
        this.vaccine_Name = vaccine_Name;
        this.vaccine_Date = vaccine_Date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getInstitution_Name() {
        return institution_Name;
    }

    public void setInstitution_Name(String institution_Name) {
        this.institution_Name = institution_Name;
    }

    public String getVaccine_Name() {
        return vaccine_Name;
    }

    public void setVaccine_Name(String vaccine_Name) {
        this.vaccine_Name = vaccine_Name;
    }

    public String getVaccine_Date() {
        return vaccine_Date;
    }

    public void setVaccine_Date(String vaccine_Date) {
        this.vaccine_Date = vaccine_Date;
    }
}
```

I want to display the vaccine_Name, institution_Name, and vaccine_Date that I call in my adapter. but  don't know how to get the data from my vaccineAdapter to the HistoryFragment.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCE7T.png) is the error I get.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csXJR.png) is the design of the app. Once I clicked the history in the bottomNavigation the error will appear.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting  `Process: com.example.phaxtrack, PID: 6030
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.Intent cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your fragment in the line `mList = getActivity().getIntent();`

The getIntent() method essentially returns **intent** not a **list** so you can't equate your mList to getActivity().getIntent()! getIntent() is used to pass data from activity to activity/fragment to activity. It returns the intent that started the activity.
Example of getIntent(),
If you start an Activity with some data,

```
String someData = "StackOverflow is awesome";  
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey", someData);
```

you can retrieve this data using getIntent in the receiver activity:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (intent != null) 
     String gotBackSomeKey = intent.getExtra("someKey");
```

Now for passing data between fragments or from an activity to a fragment, we use Bundle.(Your case)
Example of Bundle,

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putParceableArrayList("YourListTag",mList);
 FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
 fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_single, fragInfo);
 transaction.commit();
```

Make sure, unlike String or Int, you cannot pass List to your Bundle/Intent directly if you have a customized list. You will have to make your object of the list Parcelable or Serializable and then pass it like above example. You can read how to implement Parcelable/Serializable here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable

Comment: this is the error I get: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.phaxtrack.utils.PatientInfoHelperClass cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: this is how I received the data `mList = Parcels.unwrap(getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("helperClass"));`

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the error so we can determine which file has the error

Comment: Also mList = getActivity().getIntent() why us this statement there? If it is not used, can you remove it?

Comment: Please review the updated question. The picture of the error is at the bottom.

Comment: Where are you calling HistoryFragment from?